# How do I get the User Provider? - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to extend a class and all I need is the UserProvider.

I thought that passing in the   '@security.context'   service and doing the code below would do it but it doesn't work (it just says that $security_context is not an object);

```
// $security_context holds the passed in $security_context service

$security_context->getToken()->getUser(); // doesn't work
```

I'm using the FOSUserBundle if this makes a difference.

As I'm passing this into a __construct then maybe the User hasn't been created yet, but I'm not really sure what is going on.

So how do I get this User Provider? Is there a security.user_provider service?

The script allows for an array of user providers, but I only need and have one.

--

Full configuration:

services.yml:

```
  security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash: #override/extend this class
    class: Acme\MyBundle\ExtendRememberMe
    parent: security.authentication.rememberme.services.abstract
    abstract: true
    arguments:
      - "@security.context"
      - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Acme\MyBundle\ExtendRememberMe.php

```
public function __construct( $security_context, $doctrine_entity_manager ) {

    $userProviders = array( $security_context->getToken()->getUser() );

    //etc. (but error due to above line)

{
```

Comment: can you show where you defined your service and your service constructor?

Comment: Have updated. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fos user providers are **fos_user.user_provider.username** and **fos_user.user_provider.username_email**

Add `- [@fos_user.user_provider.username]` as argument.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this doesn't work. I get the same error message (not an object). I also tried $fos_user.user_provider. Thanks again and if you have any other ideas I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: It works, you need to inject the provider, and call the __construct method of the parent class.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I am calling parent::__construct but it says this error: Call to a member function supportsClass() on a non-object in /var/framework/symfony/2.3.0/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/AbstractRememberMeServices.php line 240

Comment: It works on all other occasions, and all I'm doing is passing in the value you mentioned. Is there a way to test exactly what '@fos_user.user_provider.username' provides? Also, surely '@fos_user.user_provider.username' holds the username of a user, not the UserProvider? So maybe it's not '@fos_user.user_provider.username' to get the UserProvider???

Comment: It corresponds to this class https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Security/UserProvider.php

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what that means or how that will help me. Thanks again for attempting to help, I appreciate your time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34644/discussion-between-rpg600-and-user2143356)